# Recursive method to count the size of a circular doubly linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am currently tasked with creating a recursive method to determine the length of a circular doubly linked list, that being a doubly linked list where the final node points back to the head node and vice versa.

I can't check for equality to null because due to the circular nature of the list, but the only argument I can supply is a head node, which I can't check equality to as it changes as I recurse.

My code stands as follows:

```
public int size(ListNode head) {
        if(head.element == null || head == null) return 0;
        head.element = null;
        return 1 + size(head.next);
    }
```

I've attempted to look at the element at the pointer, setting it to null then moving on such that when the method wraps around to the original head pointer, it detects the null and stops recursing. However, this does not work at all.

Comment: So, can you show some more code? Regardless of their actual names, do you have a `List` class? If so, does it have a `ListNode head` instance variable?

Comment: Be wary of recursive methods. Recurse too many times and you'll have a stack overflow just like this site itself!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "this does not work at all" you mean that you run into problems down the line because you set every element to null.
If you cannot carry information on a node and you cannot change the method parameters I don't think it is possible to solve this. Therefore I would add a new internal method to do the actual recursive counting:

```
public int size(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null) return 0;
        return 1 + recursiveSize(head.next, head);
    }

private int recursiveSize(ListNode current, ListNode start) {
        if(current == start) return 0;
        
        return 1 + recursiveSize(current.next, start)
    }
```

Comment: current == this.head to reduce the extra parameter.

Comment: Yes if this method is inside a class with meta information about the list you don't need an extra method. My answer was for a general case where you have no information besides a ListNode.